# Реализация таймера

Tags: c++, c

Позвольте вопрос:

Предположим есть клиентское приложение работающее по http и иногда бывает так, что соединение с сервером установилось, и сервер даже начал присылать данные, но раз все зависает и данные больше не приходят.

Поэтому хотелось бы отслеживать таймауты между порциями данных, которые высылает сервер.

То есть я имею call_back функции, которые вызывается каждый раз для конкретного сокета/соединения - когда приходит очередная порция данных.

Чтобы отслеживать промежутки времени между этими порция - создаю к примеру int на один сокет, в которых будет хранится время последнего вызова call_back функции.

Но теперь вопрос, а как вообще сравнивать время на предмет истечение тайм-аута?

Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно будет создать отдельный поток, в которой нужно будет запустить условную функцию мониторинга - этой переменной, через определенный период времени ?

То есть предположим у меня 1000 соединений/сокетов и соответвенно массив из 1000 int со значениями времени, в потоке я соответственно запускаю в функции мониторинга цикл, который будет через равные промежутки времени проходить по массиву int`ов и сравнивать текущее время со временем указанном в int-ах, и если разница превышает какое то значение, то дальнейшие действия.

Однако, каждое обращение, как на чтение, так и на запись придется держать под мьютексом - и что то это уже все выглядит, как то неэффективно.

Как можно это реализовать более правильным способом ?

Comment: Раз сеть уже на калбеках то и таймер можно на калбеках сделать который будет раз в секунду например пробегать и проверять таймауты.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalyan, но сравнение самого времени - все равно под мьютексом должно быть ?

Comment: Если все в одном потоке то мьютекс не нужен, если в разных то можно [атомарные инты](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) использовать без мьютексов.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalyan, ну вроде, как атомики - это по сути то же переменные под мьютексами просто в обертке. Хотя от реализации наверное зависит.

Comment: Каким именно образом вы работаете с сетью ? В одном потоке, через асинхронность ? Это низкоуровневый select/poll или какая то обертка поверх него ? Или у вас блокирующие сокеты и отдельный поток на каждое соединение ?

Comment: @Mike, в данном случае череp select, по каждому на каждое доступное ядро.

Comment: В таких случаях я обычно делал очередь таймаутов в которую добавлял после получения данных время истечения и указатель на сокет для которого таймаут. Обычно в виде двух или односвязанного списка. Если таймауты для любых ожиданий одинаковы то смело новую запись можно добавлять в конец. Если различны, то вставлять запись так что бы они были отсортированы по времени истечения. У самого select есть параметр таймаут, его выставлял в минимальное время до след события. И с цикле select при любом событии проверяем вершину этой очереди и удаляем из нее все прошедшие записи